# finding a file in directory using perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to develop a perl script that looks through all of the user's directories for a particular file name without the user having to specify the entire pathname to the file.

For example, let's say the file of interest was `data.list`. It's located in `/home/path/directory/project/userabc/data.list`. At the command line, normally the user would have to specify the pathname to the file like in order to access it, like so:

`cd /home/path/directory/project/userabc/data.list`

Instead, I want the user just to have to enter `script.pl ABC` in the command line, then the Perl script will automatically run and retrieve the information in the `data.list.` which in my case, is count the number of lines and upload it using curl. the rest is done, just the part where it can automatically locate the file

Comment: *"im start off with this but its not working as it can only find the files in its currect directory:"* - I cannot see how your script is even doing this. It just prints out the file name. There is no attempt to compare the file name against some argument. This makes me wonder what your actual problem is: getting the file name as argument from the command line, comparing the given filename against the one in `findfiles`, giving the result back .... ? Please describe the problem you actually have more clear.

Comment: that code is just something that can search for the file name, its not very relevant to the question but i thought that code will help me start

Comment: I don't get the question (is `ABC` a filename?), but it seems to be a straight-up job for [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find). LIke: `use File::Find; find(sub { if ($_ eq $filename) { say $File::Find::name } }, $dir);` (where `$filename` is the name of the sought file).  See linked docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though very feasible in Perl, this looks more appropriate in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$(find ~ -name "$1" )
wc -l "$filename"
curl .......
```

The main issue would of course be if you have multiple files `data1`, say for example `/home/user/dir1/data1` and `/home/user/dir2/data1`. You will need a way to handle that. And how you handle it would depend on your specific situation.

In Perl that would be much more complicated:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell

use strict;

# Import the module File::Find, which will do all the real work
use File::Find ();

# Set the variable $File::Find::dont_use_nlink if you're using AFS,
# since AFS cheats.

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
# Here, we "import" specific variables from the File::Find module
# The purpose is to be able to just type '$name' instead of the
# complete '$File::Find::name'.
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

# We declare the sub here; the content of the sub will be created later.
sub wanted;

#  This is a simple way to get the first argument. There is no 
# checking on validity.
our $filename=$ARGV[0];


# Traverse desired filesystem. /home is the top-directory where we
# start our seach. The sub wanted will be executed for every file 
# we find
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '/home');
exit;


sub wanted {
    # Check if the file is our desired filename
    if ( /^$filename\z/) {
        # Open the file, read it and count its lines
        my $lines=0;
        open(my $F,'<',$name) or die "Cannot open $name";
        while (<$F>){ $lines++; }
        print("$name: $lines\n");

        # Your curl command here
    }
}
```

You will need to look at the argument-parsing, for which I simply used `$ARGV[0]` and I do dont know what your curl looks like.

A more simple (though not recommended) way would be to abuse Perl as a sort of shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
my $fn=`find /home -name '$ARGV[0]'`;
chomp $fn;
my $wc=`wc -l '$fn'`;
print "$wc\n";
system ("your curl command");
```

Comment: buddy you gave me a bash when i ask for perl haha , yeah man, there is different directories to run through , so its quite hard for me and im stuck

Comment: Patience... :-) Needed to test the perl-version first. However: you see that `bash` is much easier for simple automation tasks like this.

Comment: yeah bash is easy, i did everything on bash at first, but my boss wants me to use perl :(

Comment: it says, Undefined subroutine &File::Find::name

Comment: That is odd. It works on my system (Linux Mint). I tried some obvious typo's, but I cannot reproduce your message. Also, `File::Find` should be part of the core distribution.

Comment: If you have access to CPAN, can you try installing `App::find2perl `? And then `find2perl /home -name data1`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233743/discussion-between-helpmeandroidstudio-and-ljm-dullaart).

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet demonstrates one of many ways to achieve desired result.

The code takes one parameter, a word to look for in all subdirectories inside file(s) `data.list`. And prints out a list of found files in a terminal.

The code utilizes subroutine `lookup($dir,$filename,$search)` which calls itself recursively once it come across a subdirectory.

The search starts from current working directory (in question was not specified a directory as start point).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $search = shift || die "Specify what look for";
my $fname  = 'data.list';

my $found = lookup('.',$fname,$search);

if( @$found ) {
    say for @$found;
} else {
    say 'Not found';
}

exit 0;

sub lookup {
    my $dir    = shift;
    my $fname  = shift;
    my $search = shift;

    my $files;
    my @items = glob("$dir/*");

    for my $item (@items) {
        if( -f $item && $item =~ /\b$fname\b/ ) {
            my $found;
            open my $fh, '<', $item or die $!;
            while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
                $found = 1 if $line =~ /\b$search\b/;
                if( $found ) {
                    push @{$files}, $item;
                    last;
                }
            }
            close $fh;
        }
        if( -d $item ) {
            my $ret = lookup($item,$fname,$search);
            push @{$files}, $_ for @$ret;
        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Run as `script.pl search_word`

Output sample

```
./capacitor/data.list
./examples/data.list
./examples/test/data.list
```

Reference:
[glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob),
[Perl file test operators](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-file-test-operators/)

Comment: thanks for this but i cant use the feature say as its company linux

Comment: [say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say) is a part of the perl since version 5.10. Or are you saying that you use even more antic version of perl so that this feature is not available?